# UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION (#8) in PHP?

Tags: php, file, size, max

I'm completely stuck on this one.
Whenever I upload a large file, larger than 8MB (approx), I get this error code in the $_FILES array...
I looked at the loaded extensions, but it didn't help... The max file upload is 50M and the max post is 55M.

Has anyone else had this problem before, and know of an extension that may be causing it?

**edit**: I just noticed that's it's actually caused by attempting to upload binary files (a 5KB a.out file doesn't upload). How can I allow this? What extension is blocking the upload of binary files?

Comment: does it work if you rename the file to something innocuous like a.txt?

Comment: Are you trying this on your own server? Or is it rented webspace/a shared server? If it is your own server, exactly what (webserver,php) packages did you install?

Comment: Renaming it doesn't help, I tried a.out -> a.txt, didn't do anything. It is on my own server, I had installed Apache, PHP, MySQL, mod_perl, mod_bw_limited, mod_geoip... I believe I have suhosin installed.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I will be answering my own question...
It was caused by suhosin. I went to /etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini, and uncommented these lines, and it works flawlessly now:

```
suhosin.upload.max_uploads = 10
suhosin.upload.disallow_elf = off
suhosin.upload.disallow_binary = off
suhosin.upload.remove_binary = off
```